# Vuejs/Nuxtjs : How to create dynamic V-model names without using the v-for?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js, v-model

I am encountering a tricky issue in my `Vuejs/Nuxtjs` application. In the application, I am creating multiple `Nodes` dynamically. These `Nodes` have the `Radio button` for which I have assigned a `v-model`. However, when I change the value of one `Vuejs v-model` is affecting all other `Node` Values.

I am aware that this issue is happening because of the same `v-model` being used for all `Nodes`. I would like to assign a different `V-model` to my `Radio button` but I want to do it without using the `v-for`.

I have created the sample code in the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-matan-kvqnu?file=/nuxt.config.js)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Drag and drop the `Identifiers` into the canvas. Now the `URN` will be selected.
2. Now Drag and drop another `Identifiers` into the canvas. Now the first `Identifiers Node: URN` will disappear. I am unable to handle each `Node value` independently.

The problem is arising in the file `@components/IdentifiersNode.vue` and in the radio button.

**Code sample based on the Kissu response :**

```html
<input
    id="identifierTypeURN"
    :data="identifierSyntax"
    value="URN"
    type="radio"
    name="instanceIdentifierURN"
    @input="instanceIdentifiersSyntaxChange('URN')"
>
<label for="identifierTypeURN">URN</label>
<input
    id="identifierTypeWebURI"
    :data="identifierSyntax"
    value="WebURI"
    type="radio"
    name="instanceIdentifierWebURI"
    @input="instanceIdentifiersSyntaxChange('WebURI')"
>
<label for="identifierTypeWebURI">WebURI</label>
```

Can someone please check and let me know what am I doing wrong here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-matan-kvqnu?file=/nuxt.config.js

[image]

Comment: You should probably use `:data` and `@input` rather than `v-model`, will be simpler.

Comment: @kissu Thanks a lot for the response. I am able to understand `@input` and made the respective change but I did not understand the `:data` part. I tried to remove `v-model` and added `:data` but that does not seem to work. Can you please provide some reference related to `:data` for `input type radio`? I have added a code sample in the above question for your reference.

Comment: `data` is mainly a prop here, the name is a placeholder. Replace it with what you're using as your state. Also, you may need [`model`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#model) depending on the type of event sent by a radio button. It's always a bit tricky to check those low level HTML things.

Comment: @kissu I am able to follow to a certain extent but still in a bit of confusion. Does this mean I need to create another `customized component`? And then use that custom component within my `IdentifiersNode.vue`?

Comment: No, check the event sent by the radio event.

Comment: @kissu I tried many things based on your response but I am unable to set the `default` value for the `radio button` at the beginning and assign the value based on the changes. I have updated my code in the `CodeSandbox`. Can you please once have a look and provide some suggestions?   [1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-matan-kvqnu?file=/nuxt.config.js

Comment: @kissu I tried many other things but nothing seems to work. Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated. I am unable to handle the values in each `Node` independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some effort able to get it working. I was using the `Radio button` functionalities wrongly. I changed it to something like this and it worked fine:

```html
<template>
  <div ref="el">
    <div class="header">Identifiers Node: {{ ID }}</div>
    <div id="app" class="nodeContainer">
      {{ "Value : " + identifierSyntax }}
      Syntax:
      <input
        :id="`identifierTypeURN-${ID}`"
        :data="identifierSyntax"
        value="URN"
        type="radio"
        :name="`instanceIdentifier-${ID}`"
        :checked="identifierSyntax === 'URN'"
        @input="instanceIdentifiersSyntaxChange($event, 'URN')"
      />
      <label :for="`identifierTypeURN-${ID}`">URN</label>
      <input
        :id="`identifierTypeWebURI-${ID}`"
        :data="identifierSyntax"
        value="WebURI"
        type="radio"
        :name="`instanceIdentifier-${ID}`"
        :checked="identifierSyntax === 'WebURI'"
        @input="instanceIdentifiersSyntaxChange($event, 'WebURI')"
      />
      <label :for="`identifierTypeWebURI-${ID}`">WebURI</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      ID: "",
      nodeId: "",
      bizStep: "",
      allNodeInfo: [],
      identifierSyntax: "URN",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("MOUNTED");
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      const id = this.$el.parentElement.parentElement.id;
      const data = this.$df.getNodeFromId(id.slice(5));
      this.ID = data.data.ID;
      this.nodeId = data.data.nodeId;
      this.allNodeInfo = JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(
          this.$store.state.modules.ConfigureIdentifiersInfoStore
            .identifiersArray,
          null,
          4
        )
      );
      this.identifierSyntax = this.allNodeInfo.find(
        (node) => node.identifiersId === this.nodeId
      ).identifierSyntax;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    // On change of the IdentifierSyntax change, change the value in the respective node info
    instanceIdentifiersSyntaxChange(event, syntaxValue) {
      console.log("CHANGED : " + syntaxValue);
      console.log(event.target.defaultValue);
      this.identifierSyntax = syntaxValue;
      // Change the value of the respective syntax within the Node information in IdentifiersNode array
      this.$store.commit(
        "modules/ConfigureIdentifiersInfoStore/identifiersSyntaxChange",
        { nodeId: this.ID, syntaxValue }
      );
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.header {
  background: #494949;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
</style>
```